# How to set default value for state params using a service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state with a param like,

```
.state('statename',{
   url : 'emp/:empId',
   ...
   ...
}
```

This will show the employee details for the given employee id. I want to show the logged in user's details if empId is not provided.  I have the logged in user id is a service 'User' and i need to inject this 'User' service and set the value to empId as default value.

The document says that i can set default value for params as follows,

```
.state('statename',{
   url : 'emp/:empId',
   params : {
      empId : 1
   },
   ...
}
```

I want to inject the service and provide value dynamically and i tried the following options,

#### 1

```
 ...
 params : function(User){
     return { empId : User.getLoggedInUserId() }
 } 
 ...
```

#### 2

```
 ...
 params : {
     empId : function(User){
        return User.getLoggedInUserId();
     }
 } 
 ...
```

But nothing worked. I hope those are wrong ways to do it. Is there any way through which i can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Use `resolve`. At resolve function, you can inject in any service that is needed, just like in your controller. This is also the cleanest way to do it - since no global variables are involved, and you still can get your `$stateParams` work as intended.

```
.state('statename',{
   url : 'emp/:empId',
   resolve:{
    resolve: {
      resolveEmpId: ['$stateParams', 'User', function($stateParams, User) {
        if ($stateParams.empId === "" ||$stateParams.empId === null ) {
          $stateParams.empId = User.getLoggedInUserId();
        }
        return $stateParams.empId;
      }]
   }
   ...
}
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jY9vbbG7SV2cEsKDfoYS?p=preview) to show how it works. Open it in full to see the `$stateParams` changing.

Answer (score 0):

```
state('statename', {
  url: 'emp/:empId',
  templateUrl: 'new.html',
  controller: function($scope, $stateParams, User) {
     $stateParams.empId : User.getLoggedInUserId()
  }
})
```

This may help you

Answer (score 0):

Handle the state change event and set the param there:

```
yourApp.run(function($rootScope, User) {

   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams) {
      if (!toParams.empId)
         toParams.empId = User.getLoggedInUserId();
   });

});
```